# Refactoring TS class of functions into Dictionary like object

Tags: typescript, object

I'm working on a typescript project and I want to refactor some of the items we're using to work better. I have a file that is defined as a class, but probably could just be a simple dictionary/POJO. it's defined like this:

```
export class AppSettings{
    public static get API(): string { return '/apis';}
    public static get API_COMMON(): string {return `${this.API}/common`;}
    public static get API_COMMON_VENDORS(): string {return `${this.API_COMMON}/vendors`;}
    //...ommitted as this is how everything is built...
    //... return `${PREVIOUS_API_GET}/nextURL`....
}
```

The final result is that I want to be able to access the values via indexing on the object. (i.e. `AppSettings['domain']['endpoint']`

Basically we have several "areas" or "domains" within the app. They do similar things for different use cases for our app, but operate on the same types of data. For example we have an admin portal vs the client facing app. Both have methods to interact with the data type (i.e. invoice, batch, purchase order, etc.) So to explain a bit better, a good example of a real call would be `AppSettings['admin']['getBatches']` or `AppSettings['customer']['getBatches']`

How would I refactor something like this?

Comment: I don't quite understand the desired result... What do the strings `'domain'` and `'endpoint'` correspond to in the original `class` definition?   Could you try to make this a true [mcve]?

Comment: I don't see anything about `admin`, `customer`, or `getBatches` in your `AppSettings` definition above.  All I see is `API`, `API_COMMON`, and `API_COMMON_VENDORS`.  It would be very helpful for you to connect the dots between what you have and what you want.  How do you use the current `AppSettings` definition?  I can't tell if you're just asking how to concatenate strings.   Maybe someone else can answer here but I still can't make much sense of this without a [mcve].  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just define the functions/objects like so:

```
const API = (): string => '/apis';
const API_COMMON = (): string => `${this.API}/common`;
const nested_obj =  { prop: 'thing' };
....
```

And then export them all (optionally as the default as well):

```
export {
  API,
  API_COMMON,
  nested_obj
  ...
};
```

So when you `import` the object you can use it like a dictionary/object.